# Manage multiple SIM cards by connecting them to a device at home and using them remotely

Tags: iphone, hardware-recommendation, sim

I have 3 SIM cards and I don't want to have 3 phones to manage them.

I just want to know if for example I can keep one of the cards in my phone and keep the two others in my house plugged in one device.

I just have to install an application and I can receive and send messages, calls from this application using the sim cards on my device.

And everything will work using internet.

I want to do that with my Iphone and not an other kind of phone

Something like that should exists but I can't find it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Agreed. But just because he asked. @ant I don't think anything like this exists off the shelf but with some programming skills and a rooted multi-sim Android phone I'm pretty sure you could easily build this.